# WxPerl make modal Frame

Tags: modal-dialog, wxwidgets, wxperl

I'm trying create modal window (wxFrame) in perl with xwPerl library (and WxWidget 3.0.2). Reason is, that is important for me to code will interrupt after window will be showed, until user close it. I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573660/5746693.

I would like use this code in in WxPerl library, but I have problem with using Wx::EventLoop class. It seems there is problem with loading this library. I didn't even find this class in WxWidget documentation. Sorry for probably stupid question.

Or is here some possibility to implement custom (with own controls in there)  modal frame based on WxDialog class?

Thank for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a modal window, use a `wxDialog`, not a `wxFrame`. Using the latter just doesn't make sense, the main difference between the two is that a dialog can be (and usually is) modal while the frame can't. Otherwise they are almost exactly the same.